# Copying a file from linux to windows machine using scp with out entering password

Tags: ubuntu, windows, scp, openssh

Hello i am trying to copy the file from my ubuntu machine to windows machine using scp without entering the password. I have set up the openssh key and followed the steps to enable the password less file trasfer setting by setting authorized keys. But still the scp command asks for password.

Facing issue to resolve the same. Request you to please help me on same.

Comment: Are you pushing the file from Ubuntu to Windows or are you pulling the file? Did you check the private key's permission? Have you tried increasing the debug output of the client and the server?

Comment: i am pushing from ubuntu to windows i copied public key from linux to windows as authorized_keys still issye is there.

Comment: This seems more a Windows issue than a Linux/Unix issue. See http://woshub.com/using-ssh-key-based-authentication-on-windows/

Comment: @Ljm Dullart Thank you for the response but i tried th same still  issue persist.

Comment: OK then; do `ssh -v your.windows.machine` on Ubuntu and add the output to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue by commenting `admin_authorized_keys` as it was looking for this file for authorized keys despite of `authorized_keys`.